# Display "Time spent" in the Sub-Tasks section?

Tags: jira

There's a Sub-Task section in the Task page. There are two bars agaist every sub-task indicating "Original Estimation" and "Time Spent".

I don't need those bars. Is possible to configure Jira to show me "Original Estimation" and "Time Spent" in hours (instead of bars)?

Answer (score 1):

If you already have the time tracking enabled then you can easy change the time format by the following steps:

1. Go to Jira settings -> Issues -> ISSUE FEATURES and select Time tracking;
2. Click on the "Edit global settings" button;
3. Change the "Time display format" field and select the Pretty, Days, or Hours format that will appear on an issue's Time Spent field.

Read more details [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiracloud/configuring-time-tracking-818578858.html).

Please also note a specific subtask behaviour when the remaining estimate and time spent are enabled - the parent task will have the total sum of all remaining estimates of the subtasks, find more information [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirasoftwarecloud/configuring-estimation-and-tracking-764478030.html).

Comment: Where do I find these Jira settings? (I'm not a Jira Administrator.)

Comment: You have to be a JIRA administrator to apply such configuration changes.